# Normalization of a table (BCNF)

Tags: database, relational-database, database-normalization

I'm trying to understand how to normalize a database, and one of the exercise given by our teacher was to normalize in BCNF this table:

```
Flight(**CityDeparture,CityArrival,Day**,NationDeparture,NationArrival)
```

where **(CityDeparture,CityArrival,Day)** is the primary key.
So I assumed that:

1)The city name is unique independently from the nation (there can not be two nation with the same city, even if that is not true in reality), otherwise the primary key would be wrong.

2)The functional depencies are
    CityDeparture->NationDeparture
    CityArrival->NationArrival
Meaning the table was not even in 2NF, so I decomposed it like so:
    Flight(**CityDeparture,CityArrival,Day**) 
there are no non-banal FD so it is in BNCF, right?

```
CityD(**CityDeparture**,NationDeparture) CityDeparture->NationDeparture
```

is in BNCF because CityDeparture is key

```
CityA(**CityArrival**,NationArrival) CityArrival->NationArrival
```

is in BNCF because CityArrival is key.

I also considered the fact that CityA and CityD could be identical unless every city has a different code of departure/arrival(i.e. NewYork has code 'AAA' if a flight leaves from there and code 'BBB' if a flight lands there) so one could just have a single **City(Name,Nation)** table and both CityDeparture,CityArrival would reference it.

The decomposition should also be lossless because **City.Name** is a common attribute for both tables and is key for City (I'm quite unsure about this)

When I showed this to my teacher it just scored 0 and told me to go read the book without further explanation. Now I did read the book, and the articles I found linked around here but I'm honestly clueless, so I'm asking for your advice! Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your decomposition of

```
Flight(CityDeparture,CityArrival,Day,NationDeparture,NationArrival)
```

into

```
Flight(CityDeparture,CityArrival,Day) 
CityD(CityDeparture,NationDeparture)
CityA(CityArrival,NationArrival)
```

gives you indeed BCNF.

Regarding the last step, the unification of CityD and CityA: This is not justified by your functional dependencies, and thus incorrect from a formal database perspective.  It would be justified by further context knowledge. In practice, it would of course make sense in most settings.

Keep in mind that database normalization is a formal discipline, and so are its algorithms. Substitute artificial names for your relation, e.g., R(A,B,C,D,E) with the same keys and functional dependencies - the result must be same up to renaming.

**EDIT**
This assumes that the primary key and the two functional dependencies CityDeparture->NationDeparture and CityArrival->NationArrival were given as part of the exercise - otherwise see Mike's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!My greatest fear was that I had completely misunderstood the meaning of BNCF, so It's reassuring to know that I was right about that. The unification of CityD and CityA was made after the 3 tables decomposition and under the explicit assumption that I stated before, so it could not be misinterpreted but I guess I should learn to be more formal a just stick to the exercise!
I'm just left with one doubt: in evaluating the loss of information in the decomposition (considering the 2 City relations as one) can City.Name be considered an attribute of both tables?

Comment: In the pure relational model and its normal forms, 'lossless' is usually defined in terms of the natural joins. If you want to replace CityD and CityA by just City (with attributes Name and Nation), you would have to join using explicit join conditions (as you would in SQL with JOIN ... ON ...). But of course, under the context assumption that you can unify both relations, the new schema would be 'lossless' in the sense that ... (continuing on the next commment)

Comment: `select * from OldFlight` yields the same tuples as `select f.*, d.nation as NationDeparture, a.nation as NationDeparture from Flight f join City d on f.CityDeparture = d.Name join City a on f.CityArrival = a.Name`

Answer (score 1):

> 1)The city name is unique independently from the nation (there can not be two nation with the same city, even if that is not true in reality), otherwise the primary key would be wrong.

On the one hand, your reasoning here is correct. On the other hand, many (most?) textbook normalization exercises don't include keys at all. You're usually expected to derive all possible keys from the dependencies. Maybe your teacher expects you to ignore the existing key.

Another possibility is that your teacher wanted you to include the FD {CityDeparture, CityArrival, Day} -> {NationDeparture, NationArrival}.

Another possibility is that your teacher wanted you to explore the dependencies *within* the primary key. Are there any multi-value dependencies?

If your book includes an algorithm that you can do with pencil and paper--most of them do--try working through it that way.  See what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!The exercise was not taken from our book, and the keys were given by the teacher; also we did not study any normal form beyond BNCF, so multivalued dependencies should not be considered here (nor there should be any, at least at first glance).
But I did omit the FD you quoted, so I guess that is definitely my mistake (maybe not worth a 0, but that's another story :P). I did try the algorithm and reached the 3 tables decomposition I wrote (before merging 2 tables in one), but I thought I could have made a mistake at some point, good to know I wasn't completely wrong!